# Chrome Extension Reactjs chrome.tabs

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to build a chrome extension using React and I managed to get my manifest.json set up as such:

`{
  "short_name": "GitMap",
  "name": "GitMap",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html",
    "default_title": "GitMap"
  },
  "permissions": [
        "tabs"
    ],
  "version": "1.0"
}`

. I want to access the url of the currently active tab using `chrome.tabs.query({ "currentWindow":true}, function(tab) { blahblahblah}`
within my React application's app.js file, but i'm receiving this error:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined`.

How do i access the 'chrome' method from within a react file? Thank you

Comment: The error means the library is not being loaded, hence it's not familiar with the methods you're calling. Try checking the [react-chrome-extension-boilerplate](https://github.com/jhen0409/react-chrome-extension-boilerplate) on how to use reacjts with chrome extensions.

Answer (score 0):

try this solution

1. chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function(tab){console.log(tab.url);});